# Google Maps search for duplicate lat and lng

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

For each location I'm adding a png icon.

In my database I have many entries with the same lat and lng.  Is there a way I can find the entries with the duplicate lat and lng and apply a different icon?

```
function displayStores(result){
    if (result.length > 0){
        for (i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            //Append Store Address on Sidebar
            var html = getEmbedHTML(i+1,result[i].name,result[i].address,result[i].distance);
            $("#divStores").append(html);
            //place a marker
            var image = 'images/number_' + parseInt(i+1) + '.png';
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].lat,result[i].lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image
            }); 

            var msg = 'Location : ' + result[i].name + '<br/> ';
            msg = msg + 'Address : ' + result[i].address + '<br/> ';
            attachMessage(marker, msg);
        }
    } else {
        $("#divStores").html('No Stores Found');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the points and compute the difference. When it's greater then 0 then you can change the icon.